Edge WebDriver can't create a session
I'm writing simple test cases for automatization of testing web app. Installed Maven in my VS Code, I guess made everything correct (since mvn -version returns Apache Maven 3.8.7...). Created project and tried to write some sort of setUp for WebDriver. The thing is that it calls error and I can't understand why.
Full Code:
package com.pocselenium;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
import java.io.File;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverFinder;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;


public class LogInTestCase {
    WebDriver webDriver;
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp()
    {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Documents\\GitCloneJava\\PocSelenium\\javapoc\\msedgedriver.exe");
      
        EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
        
        
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Documents\\GitCloneJava\\PocSelenium\\javapoc\\User Data");
        options.setBrowserVersion("stable");
        

        DriverFinder finder = new DriverFinder(ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(), options);
        File driverPath = new File(finder.getDriverPath());
        File browserPath = new File(finder.getBrowserPath());

        EdgeDriverService service = new EdgeDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(driverPath).build(); 
        //EdgeDriverService service = new EdgeDriverService.Builder().withLogOutput(System.out).build(); //Output of error to the console

        options.setBinary(browserPath);
        
        webDriver = new EdgeDriver(service, options);

        assertTrue(webDriver != null);
    }

    @Test
    public void logInTest()
    {
        webDriver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
}

Full Error:
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   LogInTestCase.setUp:35 » SessionNotCreated Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Microsoft Edge failed to start: crashed.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from msedge location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe is no longer running, so msedgedriver is assuming that msedge has crashed.) 
Host info: host: 'HOSTNAME', ip: 'xx.xx.xx.xx'
Build info: version: '4.20.0', revision: '866c76ca80'
System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.23'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: MicrosoftEdge, browserVersion: stable, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [user-data-dir=C:\Users\MyUser...], binary: C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr..
., extensions: []}}]}]

P.S.: Versions of used technologies:
Maven - Apache Maven 3.8.7
Java - openjdk version "21.0.3" 2024-04-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-9388422 (build 21.0.3+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-9388422 (build 21.0.3+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
Selenium - 4.20.0
I have already checked versions both of Edge and Driver, downloaded new Driver couple times, changed paths to Driver and Edge, killed all Microsoft Edge processes, tried to find out where is exception raised step-by-step (I guess it has something to deal with ClassLoader).

So the solution was to add next lines:
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");

and change content of setBrowserVersion() to appropriate version of browser.
Important: those must be the very first arguments passed.
Solution was combined out of proposed solution on this post

As of Selenium 4.6, SeleniumManager was added and it automatically takes care of downloading and configuring the appropriate driver for you. So, you no longer need to use a DriverManager or specify the path, etc.
Your code can be reduced to
public class LogInTestCase {
    WebDriver webDriver;
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp()
    {
        EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Documents\\GitCloneJava\\PocSelenium\\javapoc\\User Data");
        options.setBrowserVersion("stable");
        webDriver = new EdgeDriver(options);

        assertTrue(webDriver != null);
    }

    @Test
    public void logInTest()
    {
        webDriver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
}


Thank you for your answer, @JeffC. However it worked only once - window of Edge has been opened successfully, and program crashed again with error which says something like not able to create user default directory. I have added line of  options.addArguments("profile-directory=Default"); and hoped it will help, but it didn't.
So now my code throws the same error and doesn't opens window. I've cleaned folder with temporary profiles, just to give it a try.

Now I'm thinking about version of browser. Since I'm using corporate laptop it has preinstalled Edge 124.0.2478.121, which as says resourse is not the latest stable verion. Could it be the reason, so chrome not rechable?

You shouldn't be getting "Chrome not reachable" if you are using Edge. SeleniumManager downloads the correct corresponding version of the browser that is installed so that shouldn't be an issue. I would go through and delete all existing edgedriver instances off the computer and then run it again to make sure it's not using an existing driver.
